# NerdTree Toggle seems to overwrite my set columns=80

Tags: vimrc, plugin-nerdtree

This is my .vimrc configuration:

```
set columns=80
set linebreak
```

It works as expected but when call NerdTree Toggle the lines expand to fix the terminal window size. Even when NerdTree is deactivated the columns=80 settings doesn't come back. I have google it but just could find:

```
set winfixwidth
```

However it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your lines to be set to a certain length, then use

`set textwidth=80`

This will set the number of columns to display and works well with NERDTree for me.

Ref:
1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033423/vim-command-to-restructure-force-text-to-80-columns

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I works but again, after using the NerdTreeToggle, the lines change their width. Actually, if I use `set columns=80` after a few seconds of enabling NerdTree the column and text width is refreshed to adopt the screen width.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean by `lines change their width`? When you use `textwidth`, `vim` will put a new line `\n` after every 80 characters, unless you join the lines using something like `J`.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use `set column` as well as `set textwidth`?

Comment: The `vim` documentation states that if `VIM` is unable to change the number of columns.. the display may get messed up.. From vim docs: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'columns'